# Limit volume to a certain range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a certain program which changes the volume of a computer using the `pulsectl` module in python. The following is the code:

```
if(distance > self.threshold):
    self.pulse.volume_change_all_chans(self.sink, 0.02)
else:
    self.pulse.volume_change_all_chans(self.sink, -0.02)
```

Using this code leads to a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value can go up to infinity. What I would like to do is that the maximum value of volume should be set at one. It shouldn't increase even a bit beyond one.

For ex, if my current volume is `0.99` and the condition in `if` statement is `True`, then, my volume changes to `1.1`. This shouldn't happen. It should increase maximum to `1.0`. Never beyond it.

Also, the current value of value of volume can be obtained by `self.pulse.volume_get_all_chans(self.sink)`

How can i do this without writing too many if else conditions in python.

Comment: if(volume>1) {volume=1;}

Comment: Hint: can you think of a mathematical rule that tells you how much to increase the volume, if it's currently at 0.99? Then, you have two candidates for how much to increase the volume: the one calculated by that rule (even when inappropriate), and the constant `0.02`. Can you think of a mathematical rule that tells you which one to use (that works for all cases)?

Comment: Another approach: can you think of a rule that tells you what the volume should be after the change, given two candidates (the original plus the increment, vs. the limit value)?

Answer (score -1):

> How can i do this without writing too many if else conditions in
> python.

You might harness `max` and `min` for keeping value in certain range without any `if` at all, consider following simple example

```
RANGE_LOW = 0.0
RANGE_HIGH = 1.0
value = float(input("Provide some value: "))
value = min(value,RANGE_HIGH)
value = max(value,RANGE_LOW)
print("value was set to",value)
```

Comment: I think the OP wants this functionality to increment/decrement the volume in steps of `0.02`.